# SQL Earliest Record

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Let's say I have a table orders with 20 columns.  I'm only interested in the first 4 columns:  id, department_id, region_id, datetime where id is a customer id and datetime is the time the customer placed an order.  The other columns are more specific to product details (e.g. product_id), so on a given order, you may have multiple rows.  I'm struggling to write a query to get me the earliest department and region by each customer as the same customer can have multiple combinations of department_id and region_id.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (
    SELECT id,
        department_id,
        region_id,
        min(DATETIME) AS ts
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY id,
        department_id,
        region_id
    ) a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id,
        min(DATETIME) AS ts
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY id
    ) b
    ON a.id = b.id
        AND a.ts = b.ts
```

This seems to work, but it doesn't seem very efficient and poorly written.  Is there a better way to write this?  The table itself is fairly large, so this query is slow.

Comment: I don't see why you use the JOIN, you don't use it's values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just do:

```
SELECT id, department_id, region_id, datetime
FROM (SELECT o.*
             row_number() over (partition by id order by datetime) as seqnum
      FROM orders o
     ) o
where seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

You can try this version in to see if it works better:

```
select o.*
from orders o join
     (select id, min(datetime) as min_datetime
      from orders
      group by id
     ) oo
     on oo.id = o.id and oo.datetime = o.datetime;
```

In most databases, the `row_number()` version would probably have better performance.  However, Hive can make arcane optimization decisions and this might be better.

Comment: This is much cleaner and I've marked it as the answer, but in my case the query ran much longer (> 16 hrs) and eventually errored out for lack of resources.  I'm guessing the table was too large for the windowing function to sequence the records.

Answer (score 0):

I think you maybe could use having like this:

```
SELECT id, department_id, region_id, min(datetime) AS ts 
FROM orders 
GROUP BY id, department_id, region_id 
HAVING ts=min(datetime)
```

Comment: This won't get me to what I'm after in my case.  It'll get me the earliest record by id, department_id, region_id.  I'm after getting the earliest record by id and from that id, I'd like to know what department_id and region_id it originated from.  Semantic difference.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dense_rank()` analytic function:

```
SELECT 
        id,
        department_id,
        region_id,
        min(DATETIME) AS ts
 FROM
(
SELECT  id,
        department_id,
        region_id,
        DATETIME,
        dense_rank() over(partition by id order by DATETIME) AS rnk
  FROM orders
)s 
WHERE rnk=1 --records with minimal date by id
GROUP BY id,
         department_id,
         region_id;
```

This query does the same as yours, but the table will be scanned once, without join.